# How can I fix my Mturk submit button? It is not working

Tags: javascript

When I submitted my external HIT on Mturk, the Submit button is not working. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this. The data gets stored in my server though. Here is my code:

```
<div id="instruction3" class="instructions" style="display:none"> 
survey questions here
<a href="javascript:SaveData()" id="finalSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</a>
</div>
    
function SaveData() {
 (some code here)
 d = {   
  "trialStruct": trialStruct,
  "critStruct": critStruct
  };
  console.log(d)
  SendToServer(curID, d);
}
        
<form action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit" id="mturk_form" method="post" name="mturk_form">
<input id="assignmentId" name="assignmentId" type="hidden" value="" /> 
<p><input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
            
function SendToServer(id, curData) {
   $.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/turk/save.php",
   data : { json : JSON.stringify(curData) },
   success : function(data) { 
   document.forms[0].submit();
  }
 });
}
```

Edited: the flow should be participants click on the submit button and the data gets stored and sent to the externalSubmit page. These are parts of the code from Mturk that I need to implement in my code and perhaps I am not doing it right.

```
<!-- HTML to handle creating the HIT form -->
<form action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit" id="mturk_form" method="post" name="mturk_form">
<input id="assignmentId" name="assignmentId" type="hidden" value="" /> 

<!-- HTML to handle submitting the HIT -->
<p><input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe post more code? From what I see you are not using that function. You can add an `onsubmit` to the form and add that function.

So change it to:
`<form action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit" id="mturk_form" method="post" name="mturk_form" onsubmit="SendToServer()">`. Im not sure how the data is being set so its hard to tell, but you can figure out how to get those into the fucntion

Comment: I have added more code. Let me know if there is anything else specifically that I can add to help figure out the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should call the SaveData() function inside the form tag

```
<form action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit" id="mturk_form" method="post" name="mturk_form" onSubmit="SaveData()">
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think you should try to move the `SaveData` function to the `onSubmit` value of the form. So you would be submitting the form and the data would get saved to the server. You have extra html code above but I think that is superfluous for what you are trying to do.

```js
function SaveData() {
 (some code here)
 d = {   
  "trialStruct": trialStruct,
  "critStruct": critStruct
  };
  console.log(d)
  SendToServer(curID, d);
}
          
function SendToServer(id, curData) {
   $.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/turk/save.php",
   data : { json : JSON.stringify(curData) },
   success : function(data) { 
   document.forms[0].submit();
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<form action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit" id="mturk_form" method="post" name="mturk_form" onSubmit="SaveData()">
<input id="assignmentId" name="assignmentId" type="hidden" value="" /> 
<p><input onclick="window.location.href = https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit';"id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, the HTML code on top contains some survey questions which I removed here because it was too long. So, once participants click on the submit button, the data should be stored and they will be directed to the external submit URL.

Comment: Gotcha so after the submission of the form you want to redirect as well?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I added some information to the original post. There is some code from Mturk that I need to use but I guess I'm not implementing it correctly.

Comment: So maybe I’m wrong but in the save data function have you submit the form you simply do a ‘window.location.assign’ to change the route. Is the data not getting saved to the server when you add the save function to your form submit?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but do you mean my SaveData function in the id="finalSubmit"? With my current implementation, the data gets saved but is not redirecting to the URL.

Comment: Where does the url come from?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working one, I have used https://postman-echo.com/post just to make sure it works.

```js
function SaveData() {
  var d = {
    "trialStruct": trialStruct,
    "critStruct": critStruct
  };
  console.log(d);
  SendToServer(curID, d);
}

function SendToServer(id, curData) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://postman-echo.com/post",
    data: {
      json: JSON.stringify(curData)
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#mturk_form").submit();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="instruction3" class="instructions" style="display:none">
  <a href="javascript:SaveData()" id="finalSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</a>
</div>

<form action="https://postman-echo.com/post" id="mturk_form" method="post" name="mturk_form">
  <input id="assignmentId" name="assignmentId" type="hidden" value="" />
  <p><input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```